# SMB/connection between devices in the same network is too slow

Tags: networking, router, samba, smb, shared-folders

I shared a folder in windows (which is connected to my modem/router combo(same modem that I use for internet))
When I access(wirelessly/same network) this folder from any device I get very low speeds

Uploading to the folder: 4.7Mbit
Downloading to the folder: 13Mbit
And if I try to download multiple files it tops at around: 17Mbit

I tried running iperf3 to test if its just SMB but got the same results ,17Mbits.

My internet speed is exactly that, 17 down, 5 up (I know I know slow)

I can't figure out where the problem is, is the router locking the network speed at the internet limit even though these devices are sending to each other not to the internet?
PS: the PC that have the shared folder
[image],
and the other device (that's trying the reading/writing shows the same)

Comment: @FrankThomas yes I'm sure its Mbit ... My isp service is 17/5 aka 2.125MB/s down , 0.6MB/s up

Comment: then your best bet is either to contact your ISP, or if they won't help, add your own hardware behind the ISP's, and use it for LAN connectivity instead. that way you only use their equipment when accessing the Internet.

Comment: Since the throughput is really close to the ISP's throughput, is it certain the share isn't going through WAN, instead of LAN, due to a misconfiguration? It's never advisable to use an ISP router because ISP's retain remote access to their devices, and there have been cases of rogue employees accessing customer's LAN networks. It's always advised to use your own router as @FrankThomas suggested, putting it downstream of the ISP modem+router combo by connecting the WAN port of the ISP's modem+router combo to the WAN port of your router _(LAN to LAN port would double-NAT your router)_

Comment: @JW0914 how can I tell if its using LAN not WAN ? And if its router level problem what parameters should I be looking for ?

Comment: @JW0914 I do have an old router lying around but the computer just can't access SMB or Iperf at all (without the router having access to the internet) ,they can ping each other but no file sharing ,I looked for a solution but only found that its problem with hosts configuration or something like that, and how to fix it in Linux SMB ,but I have no idea how to do it in windows. If you know how please tell me.